# people picker control from sharepoint list to infopath 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath

I customized a SharePoint 2010 list to Infopath 2010. I have 4 people picker control in list. I want to show the control in a 2 diffrent sections in infopath. when i customize the the list to infopath evrything is working fine as per requirement means 2 people control in two diffrent section when i see in preview . but when i publish the form the people picker is npt showing there . please guide me in this regard.